# NodeJS url request, absolute or relative?

Tags: node.js

A very simple question but bothers me a lot.

what's the difference between the following two cases ?

```
index.html

 - script src="script/a.js"
 - script src="/script/a.js"  // starting with slash
```

and why my server can serve this request (starts with slash)

```
app.get('/script/a.js', function(req, res){ // with slash
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/realfolder/script/a.js');
});
```

no matter the url src on client side is any case of those two cases I just mentioned ?

On the other hand, I always got 404 error if I serve the request in the following way (starts without slash)

```
app.get('script/a.js', function(req, res){ // without slash
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/realfolder/script/a.js');
});
```

In my opinion, the path starts from '/' means the root folder of application and the other means relative path from __dirname. And I couldn't understand why my server can't handle **app.get('script/a.js')** this request which is without slash in the beginning ?

Anything wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a path starts with a slash `/` it means that it is an absolute path.
When it doesn't start with a slash, it is a relative path.

Lets see an example. Imagine that my hard disk has only the following folders:

```
main
    subfolder1
    subfolder2
        lastfolder
```

Now imagine we are in folder `subfolder2` and we want to load a file that is inside `lastfolder`. We can load it with a **relative** path:

```
lastfolder/file.txt
```

But we can also use an **absolute** path:

```
/main/subfolder2/lastfolder/file.txt
```

Both paths are correct, but the relative one can fail if we move to a different folder (for example if we are in `subfolder1`), while the absolute path will always be correct (if we don't modify the folders of course).

Comment: Thanks, I think I am aware of this concept. But I still couldn't understand why my server can't handle app.get('script/a.js') this request which is without splash in the beginning ?

Comment: well, when a relative path is not working, the first question is: where am I? Am I in the `main` folder? inside `subfolder1`? In your case, where is your Node app running? See: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/process.html#process.cwd or use absolute paths.

Comment: just make sure one thing, do you mean when the failed relative path appears, the server side will try to find this file from app root (process.cwd() as you said) ?

Comment: nope, if it fails, it fails. so you have to ensure that it doesn't fail. That's why I pointed you to `process.cwd()`. That, combined with `__dirname` will help you solve any problem with relative paths.